# How to get the synchronized block object parameter in Javassist

Tags: javassist

everybody,
I want to get the synchronized block parameter, such as

```
    String obj;  
    synchronized(obj){
        ... 
    }
```

How can I get the parameter 'obj' at byte code level using Javassist?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the low-level API of Javassist or ASM to analyze the bytecode instructions in order to do what you want.

```
 Object obj;
 synchronized(obj){
   //...
 }
```

Translates into

```
 0:   aload_0
 1:   getfield        #2; //Field obj:Ljava/lang/Object;
 4:   dup
 5:   astore_1
 6:   monitorenter
 ...
```

The *monitorenter* instruction is the start of synchronized block and astore_1 instruction just before that places the obj field value on top of the stack - that is the value you're looking for.